# Copy repeatedly a character to a string and Print the string in C

Tags: c, string

I want to print a string which is basically a repetition of characters.

I want to define a function which takes the count and character as an argument and print the string.
Main constraint is to implement without loops .

Here my starting code :

```
char *print_string ( int count, char c)
{
// String should be equivalent to count times the character

char * string 
printf ("%s\n", string);

}
```

Comment: Read a reasonable text book to do your homework.

Comment: 'without the loop' looks like a recursive solution.

Answer (score 2):

Ways to do it (without writing the code for you)

- recursion
- a while loop
- a do while loop
- a hand built for loop (label, increment, test and go to)

why not do all 4 for extra credit

Comment: thanks. But using loops is the least preference option. Needs to implement with the classic C in built functions

Comment: you need to make your question clear then , you asked how to do it without for loop. If you dont want any form of go to or loop then u have to do recursion

Answer (score 1):

By the time I got done with the code, it'd already been answered, but here it is anyways.  It uses a recursive method.

```
void print_string(int count, char c)
{
    if(count > 1)
    {
        printf("%c", c);
        count--;
        print_string(count, c);
    }

    else if(count == 1)
    {
        printf("%c\n", c);
    }
}
```

-=m0dem=-

Comment: You have an infinite recursive function.

Comment: Its not infinite at all, it goes as many times as count says to.

Comment: You are wrong. There is no condition in your function to exit the recursion.

Comment: Oh I see, it runs in the background, I'll change it.

Comment: @M0dem Your function is still invalid.

Comment: Oh, woops, I need to watch closer next time.

Answer (score 0):

There are Variable Length Arrays (VLA) in C. So you may use such an array in your function. For example

```
void print_string( size_t count, char c )
{
    char s[count + 1];

    memset( s, c, n );

    s[n] = '\0';

    printf( "%s", s );
}
```

Instead of a VLA you can dynamically allocate an array.

You can also write a recursive function. For example

```
void print_string( size_t count, char c )
{
    if ( count )
    {
        printf( "%c", c );
        print_string( count - 1, c );
    }
}
```

Comment: oooh - I like the first one - I didnt think of it - tiny side note VLA is non standard extension and quite common to see it not supported (MSVC for example)

Comment: @pm100 VLA is a standard C feature. Nevertheless it is conditionally supported.